# Dúvida sobre como adicionar uma border nessa linha

Tags: php, html

Fala galera bom estou a algumas horas e não consegui adicionar a tag de border nessa linha alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<tr  style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center" onclick="window.location = \''.$LINK.'/show/' . $auctionInfo['id'] . '\'"><td><div id="timer_' . $auctionInfo['id'] . '">' . time_left($auctionInfo['finish_time'] - time()) . '</div></td><td>' . $auctionChar->getLevel() . ' ' . getVocationName($auctionChar->getVocation(), $auctionChar->getPromotion()) . '</td><td>' . $auctionInfo['buy_now'] . ' pp</td><td>' . $auctionInfo['bid'] . ' pp</td></tr>';
```

caso precisar da page toda só falar que eu posto eu estou tentando adicionar a tag border para ficar um pouco mais organizado e separado mas não adianta como eu coloque ou onde não muda se alguém puder dar uma força

Print da page

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara explica melhor o que vc precisa. Vc quer colocar borda na tabela ou que colocar uma margem entre os campos?

Comment: eu quero colocar a borda na tabela ... porque ali naquele tempo etc... e possivel clicar e vai ser redirecionado para outra aba então preciso que fique com borda separados entende?

Comment: Na tag `<table>` que está por fora da sua `<tr>` coloca assim `<table border="1px" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">`

Comment: muito obrigado hugo xD

Comment: Deu certo ai? Posso adicionar como resposta?

Comment: pode sim hugo obrigado

Comment: Valeu Brunds já respondi ai, se puder aceitar eu agradeço, assim mantemos o site organizado com as perguntas que já está resolvidas com uma resposta aceita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme dito no comentário, na tag `<table>` que está por fora da sua `<tr>` coloca assim `<table border="1px" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">`

Veja como fica no exemplo, repare que todo o conteúdo agora está separado pelas bordas. Vc ainda pode usar um `padding` nas `<td>` caso queira distanciar o conteúdo das bordas.

```html
<table border="1px" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr style="font-size: 12px;text-align: center" onclick="window.location = \''.$LINK.'/show/' . $auctionInfo['id'] . '\'">
        <td>
            <div id="timer_' . $auctionInfo['id'] . '">' . time_left($auctionInfo['finish_time'] - time()) . '</div>
        </td>
        <td>' . $auctionChar->getLevel() . ' ' . getVocationName($auctionChar->getVocation(), $auctionChar->getPromotion()) . '</td>
        <td>' . $auctionInfo['buy_now'] . ' pp</td>
        <td>' . $auctionInfo['bid'] . ' pp</td>
    </tr>';
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}

td {
    padding: 10px 0;     /* 10px top & bottom padding, 0px left & right */
    border-width: 1px 0; /*  1px top & bottom border,  0px left & right */
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Alex, dê uma explicada no seu código. Principalmente porque o usuário está usando o estilo `inline`.

Comment: opa então como eu usaria esse código e um php eu colocaria ele em alguma parte especifica?

Comment: Só coloquei a parte do css que vc utilizaria, desta forma que está ai, se vc referenciar o css , ou mesmo colocar ele no corpo do seu html <style></style> , qualquer table que vc criar e seus respectivos td (coluna) vão pegar e desenhar as linhas que vc queria.